# asterisk - How to get queue caller wait time

Tags: queue, asterisk

asterisk 1.4.36

- is their any event or variable that give me the caller wait time on queue?
- i want to display the agent that answered the call, the time the the customer actually wait.
- i don't need the queue avg wait time, only the time that this specific caller waits on the queue before the call was Answered be the Agent.

i have already try to find solutions like getting the data by using "show queue XXX" function

i am using asterisk **1.4.36** .

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is queue_log in /var/log/asterisk/

Also posible put that info in database.

Comment: i am looking for event or variable

Comment: every action that saved in queue_log also throw event. there are no any variable like that.